Dynamic Routing in NUXT JS
So i am trying to use nuxtJS dynamic routing and all the documentation tells me to use [] in creating dynamic routing for Nuxt 3 which i did but it didnt work. i decided to use _id which i belived is the Nuxt 2 convention. which eventually work. now i am wondering why this is so. why is it possible the _id method work on Nuxt 3 and not the [id] convention i have been trying to use all day.
|-page
  -[id]

but this works
|-page
  -_id


Which nuxt version are you using? Also it should be pages: https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/routing/pages As for why the old version might still work? Retro-compatibility. If you still have an issue, a [repro] is very welcome.
